# Horizontal List items with various width

Tags: css

In the top bar, How can the green and the red "li" area be made with width 3em?, I tried my css as in the code but all the 3 list items remain with equal width.

It will be displayed in a mobile app webView.

Thank you

[image]

```css
ul {
   text-align: center;
}

li {
   height: 2em;
   line-height: 2em;
}

.menuIconLeft {
   width: 3em;
   background-color: green;
}

.menuIconRight {
   width: 3em;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>RRR</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyle.css"/>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
               <ul class="center">
                  <li class="menuIconLeft">
                     &#9776;
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     Activity label
                  </li>
                  <li class="menuIconRight">
                     &#8942;
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-content">
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, temporibus, dolore! Doloribus, at repellendus sunt consectetur modi natus suscipit magni explicabo optio sequi, assumenda delectus perferendis excepturi nisi nobis ratione.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos repellendus aliquam sint atque aliquid, tempore voluptatum recusandae et rerum, qui quasi ex at aspernatur. Temporibus voluptatum exercitationem sit modi assumenda!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam voluptatum illum maxime hic ipsa odio eaque cum. Optio cumque sequi recusandae. Nihil voluptatibus soluta ad saepe, quia optio laudantium molestiae.contents of this activity Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores nulla facere soluta tempore nihil, voluptatibus nostrum sequi, voluptate, incidunt distinctio reiciendis qui at totam alias. Culpa fuga rem vitae nesciunt?
            </p>
         </div>
         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
               <ul class="center">
                  <li>
                     NO
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     EXTRA
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     YES
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the middle li to expand and take the rest of the screen width but this solution is fixing the middle li as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adhere to the result you where looking for you needed to:

1. Set your list items display attribute to `display: inline-block`.
2. Set your unordered list to `list-style-type: none` so the list item bullets do not show.
3. Set your left and right list elements to `float: left` and `float: right` respectively, this helps a lot because your left and right list elements will be center aligned (due to your `ul { text-align: center }`), so they will not flush left and right unless you tell them to.
4. I added a new class `menuIconCenter` to the middle list element. This applies a width of `width: calc(100% - 6em);`, since the left and right list elements are each 3em in width, then substracting both these widths by 100% will yield the remaining width of your center list element.

   > "How can the green and the red "li" area be made with width 3em?"
5. Added a `header` and `footer` class, to help differentiate how the footer and header sections work. This is an important architectural change, can you tell why?
6. Added `<b>` to bold the text in the footer.

**Suggestion**: if you want to make these list elements clickable or work like buttons do the following *(this is in pseudocode!)*:

```
<li>
    <a href="some URL">Something here</a>
</li>

li > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any questions please ask in the comments below :-)

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 320px;
}

li {
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.menuIconLeft {
  float: right;
  width: 3em;
}
.menuIconCenter {
  width: calc(100% - 6em);
}
.menuIconRight {
  float: left;
  width: 3em;
}
.center {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header .menuIconLeft {
  background-color: green;
}
.header .menuIconRight {
  background-color: red;
}
.header .center {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.footer .center {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
  <div class="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
      <ul class="center">
        <li class="menuIconLeft">
          &#9776;
        </li>
        <li class="menuIconCenter">
          Activity label
        </li>
        <li class="menuIconRight">
          &#8942;
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, temporibus, dolore! Doloribus, at repellendus sunt consectetur modi natus suscipit magni explicabo optio sequi, assumenda delectus perferendis excepturi nisi nobis ratione.Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos repellendus aliquam sint atque aliquid, tempore voluptatum recusandae et rerum, qui quasi ex at aspernatur. Temporibus voluptatum exercitationem sit modi assumenda!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Laboriosam voluptatum illum maxime hic ipsa odio eaque cum. Optio cumque sequi recusandae. Nihil voluptatibus soluta ad saepe, quia optio laudantium molestiae.contents of this activity Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Asperiores nulla facere soluta tempore nihil, voluptatibus nostrum sequi, voluptate, incidunt distinctio reiciendis qui at totam alias. Culpa fuga rem vitae nesciunt?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
      <ul class="center">
        <li class="menuIconLeft">
          <b>NO</b>
        </li>
        <li class="menuIconCenter">
          <b>EXTRA</b>
        </li>
        <li class="menuIconRight">
          <b>YES</b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: clicking Run code snippet button did not give what I want (red and green li width 3em and middle li takes the rest of the screen width) plus it left the bottom li not on the same horizontal line but lowered the middle li . I am using safari.

Comment: @FredJ. thanks for clarifying, I modified the answer to work with how you need it to work

Comment: I moved   list-style-type: none; from the class .center to the selector ul in the css file, I hope that what you meant :). plus when I copy the code to my project. it does not apply the size changes but remains as it was before.

Comment: @FredJ. make sure your project is not overriding the CSS rules I applied on my snippet, that could very well be the case. If you copy my snippet with nothing else, the rules should apply (try it).

Comment: Even when I open the index.html in a browser > File open, with the aptana closed so that the project does not affect it. It still does not fix it, It looks nice when Run code snippet on this site only. not sure why.

Comment: @FredJ. that is odd, however I can't truly see what you are dealing with from my end. My best suggestion is to try a new project without any code but the one I wrote and see if it works. A simple HTML file with the CSS on another file, linked by a reference to the CSS file should do. It's all about fishing out the *causes* for failure, which should not exist.

Comment: removing <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/> from the head fixed it. humm but I need this later for the rest of my work

Comment: @FredJ. That was necessary for the code to work on this website, good catch!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help, I really learned a lot. how can I use query.mobile-1.4.5.css in my project later? Does that need to be in a separate question? :)

Comment: If you need jQuery (any version) you can add it to your project by putting the script tag **below** your body element

Comment: I tried that but it rendered all the changes we did to fix this issue inactive, so back to square 1. ;)

Comment: @FredJ. Then yes this would be good to ask in a new question, make sure you add any relevant details I'm sure you'll get all the help you need :)